# how to get the remaining time of the Playing song which is played using MPMusicPlayerController?

Tags: ios, mpmusicplayercontroller

I want to display remaining time time of playing song in my app,my code:

```
NSTimeInterval currentTime= musicPlayer.currentPlaybackTime; 
NSNumber *duration = [musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration]; 
NSLog(@"Current Playback Time: %f",currentTime);
```

Comment: `duration-[currentTime integerValue]`
?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to reproduce the times shown in the Music app:

```
double nowPlayingItemDuration = [[[musicPlayer nowPlayingItem] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration]doubleValue];
double currentTime = (double) [musicPlayer currentPlaybackTime];
double remainingTime = nowPlayingItemDuration - currentTime;

NSString *timeElapsed;
NSString *timeRemaining;

if (nowPlayingItemDuration >= 3600.0) {
    timeElapsed = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%02d:%02d:%02d",
                           (int)currentTime/3600,
                           (int) (currentTime/60)%60,
                           (int) currentTime%60];
    timeRemaining = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"- %02d:%02d:%02d",
                             (int)remainingTime/3600,
                             (int) (remainingTime/60)%60,
                             (int) remainingTime%60];

} else {
    timeElapsed = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%02d:%02d",
                           (int) currentTime/60,
                           (int) currentTime%60];
    timeRemaining = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"- %02d:%02d",
                             (int) remainingTime/60,
                             (int) remainingTime%60];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to show that in a progress view then follow below code.It will help you.

> ```
>  MPMediaItem *temp;
>     NSTimeInterval trackLength = [[temp valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration] doubleValue];
>     song.songDuration = [temp valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration];
> ```

```
NSTimer *timer= [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                                target:self
                                              selector:@selector(updateProgress)
                                              userInfo:nil
                                               repeats:YES];

-(void) updateProgress{
itemDur++;
        WASong *song = [self.songObjects objectAtIndex:self.cellIndexPath.row];

        CGFloat progress =itemDur/[song.songDuration doubleValue];

}
```